# Static Resource image on a single pdf page

Tags: visualforce, css, static-resources

I would like to have my image on the first page of my pdf as a background image and then the following data I have currently such as tables and text. I am not sure how to do this. At the moment my image is the background image where my tables are but I would like there to be seperate pages.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false" 
standardStylesheets="false" renderAs="pdf"  id="mypage" applyBodyTag="false">
<head>
    <style>
     @page {
        size:landscape;
     }

    body {
            font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; 
            color:rgb(0, 45, 106); 
            background-image:url('{!$Resource.myImage}');  //THIS IS MY IMAGE I WANT TO DISPLAY ON A SEPERATE PAGE
         }

    h1 { font-size: 150%; font-weight:bold; }

    h2 { font-size: 95%;
         background-color: white;
         padding: 10px;
         text-align: left;
        width: 45.00%;
        }


    /* Style the header */
    .header {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    /* Style the footer */
    .footer {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
    <h1> <apex:outputText value="{!Account.Name}" />  </h1>
    </div>

         <div class="column">
             <h2>Table 1 </h2>
                <table>
                    <th>Title 1</th>
                    <tr >
                    <td>Title 1</td>
                    <td>Title 2</td>
                    <td>Title 3</td>
                    <td>Title 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!Account.customrelasionship}" var="ac">
                    <tr>
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!ac.Name}" /></td>
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!ac.field1}" /></td>
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!ac.field2}" /></td>
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!ac.field3}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>   
                </table>

                <!--ECT -->
 </body>
</apex:page>
```

So to sum up, how do I show my $Resource.myImage on 1 page of my pdf and the rest of the other tables/data on the other page?

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the background image(myImage.png/gif/jpg) in a folder
2. Create a CSS file customCss.css with below code

   body{ background-image:url("images/myImage.png/gif/jpg") }
3. Now Zip up the image folder and the CSS file together as imageStyle.zip
4. Now goto Your Name | Setup | Develop | Static Resources | New | Name as MyStyles| Upload imageStyle.zip | Save
5. Now, Modify your visualforce page, add the below line

   ```
   <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.MyStyles, 'customCss.css')}"/>
   ```